# Place a default option into a select that can still retain a previously selected value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Dont yell duplicate just yet.
I can't find an answer for this anywhere.

I'm writing a little plugin for my web app and I want all the select boxes to have a disabled default option: `<option disabled='disabled'>-Select-</option>`.

That would be easy to do, except the user can come back in and edit their information. So i need to check if the select has a value selected:

```
 if ($this.val()) {
                            ...
                        } else {
                            $this.prepend("<option disabled='disabled' class='disabled'>-Select-</option>")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        }
```

I have attempted other solutions, that is just an example.

Edit: The idea is that the first time they come in or if they haven't previously selected it will be defaulted to that disabled select option

A problem arises where the browser sets a default option itself (the first one). Then the $this.val() has a value, when in fact the user has not selected a value.

So the question is:
**How do you place a default option into a select that can still retain a previously selected value using jquery?**

Comment: But how would the user know which option is selected?

Comment: The idea is that the first time they come in or if they haven't previously selected it will be defaulted to that disabled select option

Comment: You can't default to a disabled option, that's why it's disabled. If I understand correctly you want to give some info to the user with that first option but make it disappear when they choose something in the dropdown, is that right?

Comment: I don't want it do appear on page load if the user has previously selected that option on the page before. Ie, they can access the page multiple times. But until they actually choose a value from the drop down and save it, it will appear as default (I am able to default a disabled option, i have done it before.)

Comment: But if you reload a page it will revert to defaults in most browsers unless you save that info in a cookie or something.

Comment: Okay here is the scenario.... (damn enter button)EDIT: User logs in-> accesses their information (page load)-> fills one thing (lets say out of ten) out -> saves -> logs out. User returns later-> goes back to their information -> defaults are there except for the one that they changed/entered previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i am doing now is making my own HTML helper for dropdownlistfor.

It inserts the user's database value into the select tag and then javascript gets it from there.

**HtmlHelper**

```
public static class MvcHtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
        object htmlAttributes, bool userSelection)
    {
        if (userSelection == true)
        {
            object additionalAttributes = new { userSelection = expression.};

            var newHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            foreach (var item in new RouteValueDictionary(additionalAttributes))
            {
                newHtmlAttributes[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            return Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, newHtmlAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            return Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $selectTemplate = $("<option disabled='disabled' class='disabled'>-Select-</option>");
            $this.prepend($selectTemplate);
            if ($this.filter("[userSelection]").attr("userSelection") > 0) {
                $this.val($this.attr("userSelection"));
            } else {
                $this[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. Correct me if I'm wrong. This will set a default option (first option) and then remove it when the user selects an actual option from the dropdown.

**html:**

```
<select id="select">
    <option>Default Option</option>
    <option>Option One</option>
    <option>Option Two</option>
    <option>Option Three</option>
</select>
```

**jQ:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $defaultOpt = $(this).find('option:contains(Default Option)');
    if ($defaultOpt) { $defaultOpt.remove(); }
});
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/LWfJM/

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to remove it when they are on the page. I want to remove it if they have selected it on that page before and return to the page at a later date.

Comment: Then you'll have to store that information somewhere. As I said, a cookie, or a database or something like that.

Comment: Well I have it returned from the database when the page is loaded. So if they have previously selected an option then it will select that option automatically. But then i don't want to override that with javascript because they have edited it previously.

Comment: In this case I suggest that you render your default option in the backend, something like `<?php if(!previousSelectedOption): ?><option>Default Option</option><?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I see...Then why don't you render it in backend with a different class if `prevSelOpt==true` and then hide it with JS in frontend? That way it won't mess up your ids. Just an idea...

Comment: I couldn't set the class of an option with the htmlhelpers built into mvc3 without recreating the way i create my drop downs. And it would become clunky and silly. It seems like i may need to put a value into the select tag and read from that to see if there are any previously selected items, then check against that.

Comment: That seems doable...I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I've put myself in an impossible situation.